# Converting multiple images into Base64 string and and save it in folder with txt extension

Tags: python, json, image, base64

```
import base64
import json
import uuid
import os
from os import listdir


file_path="C:/Users/***/Documents/Projects/Falsk_API_Img2Base64/image/"

output_path="base64_txt_folder/"

Unique_ID = uuid.uuid1()

def create_image_file(images):
    input_path=os.path.join(file_path, images)
    with open(input_path, "rb") as image2string:
        converted_string = base64.b64encode(image2string.read()).decode('ascii')
        payload = json.dumps({"imagedata": converted_string})
        file = open(output_path+'image_'+str(Unique_ID)+'.txt', 'w')
        file.write(payload)
        file.close()      

for images in os.listdir(file_path):
    create_image_file(images)
```

I am trying to encode a set of images (100 images in folder) to base64 format and save it in text format individually in the output folder. This code is taking only one image for converting it to base64 and exiting from the loop. It is not taking the next image for conversion. The requirement is, if I run this code, it has to take one image at a time and convert it into base64 format and save that string in JSON format in a text file, and then it has to take 2nd image to conversion and save it in text format and so on till the last image in the folder.

[image: Please take a look at the image]

Comment: They're all being written to the same Unique_ID; you need to generate a new one each time, in the function

Comment: No worries. More generally, have a read through [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) or another introductory guide to debugging?

Comment: (Also, as a style suggestion, use a `with` statement for both of the files, rather than closing the output file manually)

Comment: A small suggestion, your variable name is confusing, `images` is plural, implying a list of things, but it is just one item, you should remove s at the end.